# SharePoint 2010 - Can we make multiple connections from the same web part?

Tags: sharepoint, web

We are creating a report where the requirement is:
1. Cascaded Filters
2. Excel Report

We have created our own filter web part which supports cascading. In order to do that we need to add multiple filter web parts on the page and connect those web part.

This we are able to achieve successfully but now the issue is we cannot create multiple connections from the filter web part (one with another filter web part and one with excel report).

Any idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `AllowMultipleConnections=TRUE`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.connectionconsumerattribute.allowsmultipleconnections(vs.80).aspx